# How do I reduce repetitive error handling in java

Tags: java, exception, coding-style, conventions

So I have a code snippet similar to this. I feel like the if statements should be in a common function. I am not sure how to handle that because school and student should be passed to this function but they are of different types.

```
Teacher teacher = school.getTeachers();
if(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(teachers) {
    log.error(”cannot find teachers in school” + school.getSchoolName());
    throw new Exception(”xyz”);
} 
Student student = teacher.getStudents();
if(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(student)) {
    log.error(”cannot find students in school” + school.getSchoolName());
    throw new Exception(”xyz”);
```

Comment: Do `Teacher` and `Student` represent one or multiple teachers/students? The name suggests one, but the value you assign (`getTeachers()`, `getStudents()`) suggests multiple. Isn't it valid for a teacher not to have any students, such as right when they've started?

Comment: what type is the argument of `isEmpty()`?

Comment: So it is one teachers and one student. Assuming a 1:1 mapping. Yeah if there are no students we want to throw the error.

Comment: Using this for the isEmpty https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ObjectUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.Object)

Comment: so what I asked for is `Object` - and that is exactly how you can handle it, as `Object`: `void check(Object obj) { if (ObjectUtil.isEmpty(obj)) { log.error( ...` and `Teacher teacher = school.getTeacher(); check(teacher);` A bit more advanced, use a generic method that returns its argument, similar to [`requireNonNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)))

Answer (score 3):

One way is to consider this case (and similar ones) in your class design. You could use inheritance. Let's say Teacher and Student inherit from Person. This way the code will be easier to extend in case you need to consider some more common logics for both classes of Teacher/Student. Create your own exception handler taking the Person class. You could use Optional in Java to throw your exception. For your log message, you can use the class name

Comment: That makes sense, however, I am unable to make any edits on student or teacher objects

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There a different ways of handling your case. First of all, you are right that Teacher and Student are different types or classes, but all classes in Java have the common superclass Object, see also [Object class (Java SE 21 & JDK 21)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html). So you can at least rely on the Object class for a common/generic solution.

If you want your logic to throw an exception based on your condition be encapsulated in a method, you can use this approach:

```
private void assertSchoolPropertyNotEmpty(Object schoolProperty, String propertyName, String schoolName) {
    if(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(schoolProperty)) {
        log.error(String.format("cannot find %s in school %s", propertyName, schoolName));
        throw new Exception("xyz");
    }
}
```